# PHP code to take a list of items that are separated by commas from database and put them in a list form

Tags: php, html, html-lists

Not sure if this is the best way as far as database design goes, but I have a TEXT type in my database that has a bunch of items separated by commas (item1, item2, item3, item4). However, I wanted it outputted as:

- item1
- item2
- item3
- item4

So does anyone have the code to do this or should I just go ahead and normalize my table?

Comment: If there are only four items and if its just a static data for retrieving, where you are not doing any search on this column.  Than it makes sense to store in db by separating it with comma.  If you are doing any search on this item, then optimize the table.

Comment: SO is not http://gimme-teh-codez.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to turn that string into an array and then loop through it to output the data 

if you need to search the database for any content of that field it would make sense to normalise the db table though.

Comment: All right, thanks for the explode function (never used it before). It looks like I'll need to normalize it because I'll be searching.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$items = explode(",", $string_from_db);
echo '<ul>';
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo '<li>' . trim($item) . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

explode() takes the string and seperates it into an array based on the specified character.
You then loop through the array and output each list item.
trim() will remove any whitespace from either end.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. As far as normalizing your tables go ... that's dependent on your usage of this data, and isn't really related to PHP at all. You would really need to tell us more about your database design, whether there are only 4 list items, or if it's variable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with explode()

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

What you have tried?